# Taking a screenshot with headless Chrome driver not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of an image on a website with Selenium and headless Chrome driver. Two steps are involved in this process. First, I identify an area on the website which I need to click (its a full screen button which gets me a full image). Second part is taking the screenshot. Everything works perfectly fine when i run it in the non-headless mode. However, when I switch to headless, I take a screenshot of a completely wrong part of the website, as if the script was ignoring the part which clicks the full screen button. Below is a relevant portion of my script.

```
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 
    20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.fullscreen')))
    driver.execute_script("return 
    arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)

    element.click()

    element = driver.find_element_by_id('id')

    png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
    driver.quit()
```